# totally stumped by uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

For a gem I'm working on, I keep getting an error for an uninitialized constant. I don't see how it's not finding this file. I'm especially stumped because I have a similar file in the same location with the same syntax, and it's being read just fine.

I'm not exactly sure which files to include, so put file names you want to see in the comments if it would help.

lib/gender.rb:

```
class TextEng::Gender
  ...
end
```

spec/gender_spec.rb:

```
require_relative 'spec_helper'

describe TextEng::Gender do #this is the line that's throwing an error
   ...
end
```

text_eng.gemspec:

```
$:.push File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)
```

And here is the error:

```
/Users/stevenspiel/text_eng/spec/gender_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant TextEng::Gender (NameError)
    from /Users/stevenspiel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load'
    from /Users/stevenspiel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/stevenspiel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'
    from /Users/stevenspiel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/stevenspiel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/stevenspiel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from /Users/stevenspiel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

## Edit

As Matheus, points out, I can simply `require_relative '../lib/gender'` in gender_spec.rb, but the thing that is stumping me is that I have a file in the same directory, doing basically the same thing, just with a different name and it works fine. The file structure looks like this.

lib/name.rb:

```
class TextEng::Name
  ...
end
```

spec/gender_spec.rb

```
require_relative 'spec_helper'

describe TextEng::Name do # this line does not throw any errors
  ...
end
```

Why is that?

Comment: Perhaps `spec_helper` has something to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spec/gender_spec.rb` doesn't seem to know about the `TextEng::Gender` class. You should require the file that defines the class before you attempt to use it:

```
require 'gender'

describe TextEng::Gender do
  # ...
end
```

Note that, per rubygems conventions, the `TextEng::Gender` class should be defined in the `lib/text_eng/gender.rb` file, so the `require` call should look like:

```
require 'text_eng/gender'
```

Comment: Thank you, Matheus. That did work, but I figured I shouldn't have to require it, especially because a file in the same directory had no problems. I'll update my answer to include that file and its spec test.